# Using object in template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I get user information by id like this

```
Template.registerHelper( 'getInfo', (id) => {
    return getInfo.find({ _id: id}).fetch()
});
```

And I use this in a each loop like this

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{getInfo post_user_id}}
{{/each}}
```

But it seems only [object Object] in template.

> [object Object]

How can I achieve this? Do I get user information as following:

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{getInfo post_user_id}}.user_name
{{/each}}
```

My codes are like these:

```
Users = new Mongo.Collection('users');
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');


Posts.insert({ text: "text 1", post_user_id: "1"});
Posts.insert({ text: "text 2", post_user_id: "1"});
Posts.insert({ text: "text 3", post_user_id: "1"});
Posts.insert({ text: "text 4 is from user id 2", post_user_id: "2"});

Users.insert({ user_name: "jack", _id: 1});
Users.insert({ user_name: "another user", _id: 2});

Template.registerHelper( 'getInfo', (id) => {
    return Users.find({ _id: id}).fetch()
});

Template.posts.helpers({
    posts() {
        return Posts.find({}, { sort: { limit: 50, createdAt: -1 } });
    },
});
```

Comment: please put your sample code somewhere like in jsfiddle

Comment: Your helper should return a string that can be directly inserted to the DOM.

Comment: @Thernys I added something to my codes. It is not possible to run it online. Or I cant do it.

Comment: @Thernys but I need to get particular values of user. If I write for email, password, user_name or more, my codes will be very very long.

Comment: @Yogesh Jagdale . It is not possible to run it online. Or I cant do it. I updated my post.

Comment: I haven't actually used Meteor so I can't give very specific details. There is probably something akin to computed properties, where you could then access `post`'s relationships in the `{{#each}}` loop with something like `{{this.user.user_name}}`. Quick googling turned up https://forums.meteor.com/t/best-practices-for-computed-values-in-meteor-document-and-collection-level/5079 and from there https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/collection-helpers as potentially relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with adding one more parameter to my function

```
Template.registerHelper( 'getInfo', (id, field) => {
    return Users.findOne({ _id: id}).[field] // <--
});
```

Regards.